# Store a collection of collections not models?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using a collection to group related models. All the models are of the same type.

This results in multiple collections for the same general set of models.

I need a way to organize these groupings (collections).

- Should I put them in a parent collection somehow?
- Should I set them all in a parent model?
- Should the initial grouping be done into a parent model instead of a 
  collection?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: You should refine your question, the answer depends on what you need to do with these models.

Comment: Do your 'multiple collections' contain unique models?  i.e. can model 123 appear in collection A and collection B?

Comment: @timDunham They are all unique, no overlapping in the sub collections.

Answer (score 0):

I currently have this:

```
appModel -> PageCollection -> PageModel -> StreamCollection -> StreamModel -> StreamItem Collection -> StreamItemModel
```

You should look into Backbone-Relational to see if the HasMany relations would work for you:
https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational

My setup looks like this in Backbone-Relational:

```
appModel (HasMany) Pages
PageModel (HasMany) Streams
StreamModel (HasMany) StreamItems
```

It works nicely